# How to print out `&` n times in @each or @for

Tags: sass, iterator

I have the following loop in my SCSS:

```
@for $i from 1 to 5 {
    .thing-#{$i} {
        @if $i == 1 {
            & + & { /* some styles */ }
        }

        @if $i == 2 {
            & + & + & { /* some styles */ }
        }

        @if $i == 3 {
            & + & + & + & { /* some styles */ }
        }

        @if $i == 4 {
            & + & + & + & + & { /* some styles */ }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the in-built SASS functions to make the code build the lines with the `& + &` programatically?

The algorithm would be:

```
& + ((+ &) * $i) { /* styles */ }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't implement each function with this syntax, you will come up with this syntax error `Invalid CSS after "@each $i ": expected "in", was "from 1 to 5 {"`. You should use `for` function.

If you convert this function to an algorithm you will come with the same styles for each step. If you would like something like that you could try the following:

```
$var: #{"&"};

@for $i from 1 to 5 {

  .thing-#{$i} {
    #{append($var, #{"+ &"})} {
      color: red;
    }
  }

  $var: append($var, #{"+ &"});
}
```

The output will be

```
.thing-1 + .thing-1 {
  color: red;
}

.thing-2 + .thing-2 + .thing-2 {
  color: red;
}

.thing-3 + .thing-3 + .thing-3 + .thing-3 {
  color: red;
}

.thing-4 + .thing-4 + .thing-4 + .thing-4 + .thing-4 {
  color: red;
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/84189d6ae6c5a342668e